# Mouse events stop working after d3 graph, zoom loads

Tags: d3.js, canvas, coffeescript, backbone-events, spine.js

On my page, I have some events defined using Spine's controller events. They are assigned to selectors using jQuery's delegate, and they work fine:

```
events:
  'click #zoom a': 'zoom'
  'mouseenter #zoom a': -> $("#yZoom_help").show()
  'mouseleave #zoom a': -> $("#yZoom_help").delay(1600).fadeOut 1600
```

Asynchronously at some point later in time, I set up some things with d3. Specifically, I am setting up zoom behavior on a canvas, a bunch of axes, etc.

```
@x_scale = d3.scale.linear() 
  .domain([@lcData.start, @lcData.end])
  .range([0, @width])    
@y_scale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([@lcData.ymin, @lcData.ymax])
  .range([@h_graph, 0])

@zoom_graph = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .x(@x_scale)
  .scaleExtent([1, @max_zoom])
  .on("zoom", @graph_zoom)

@canvas = d3.select("#graph_canvas")   
  .attr("width", @width)
  .attr("height", @h_graph)
  .call(@zoom_graph)
  .node().getContext("2d")     

# ... some other things left out
```

The problem is that after I go through this d3 setup stuff, the mouse events on the non-d3 elements stop working. They just don't work at all. The elements have the highest z-index and are not obscured by any canvas or svg elements, but they stop detecting any mouse events.

d3 should only be activating mouse events on the canvas, right? Is there some d3 magic going on that is taking over the mouse on the entire page? For example, d3 inserts this div in the body:

[image: Magic d3 div?]

**EDIT: If you want to see what I mean, go to this link:**

http://korhal.andrewmao.net:9294/#/sources/APH10154043

There is a little icon in the top left that changes color when you hover. This is the one with the mouse events; it is supposed to display a message. Once the page loads, it stops working. If you want to see it work, just reload the page and disable the JSONP call in your debugger, which prevents the function that sets up d3 from executing.

Answer (score 0):

What happened here actually had nothing to do with d3. It seems that I was inadvertently calling `@render` twice during the loading of my Spine app, making all the elements get unbound from their events, when a view was appended.

Rebinding could be done with a call to `@delegateEvents(@events)` followed by `@refreshElements`, but in this case it was simply better to fix the superfluous `@render` call.

Related question with backbone: [Why Backbone events on replacing html does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9384366/586086)